# is there any source for finding out aws services which support tags?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there any easy way to find the consolidated AWS Services which has tags?

I am currently looking each service in AWS documentation and finding out, which is tedious.

For example - services like ec2,s3,lambda,dynamodb - has tagging feature, so that resources can be identified by tags(assuming they are tagged).

Services like sns,sqs - do not have tagging option.

Need to identify a list of AWS services which do not support tagging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check: [Supported Resources for Tag Editor Tagging (Console)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsconsolehelpdocs/latest/gsg/supported-resources.html#supported-resources-tagging-console)

for services and resources that can be tagged using AWS Console.

[image]

Comment: The console tag editor, and even resource groups themselves, only support a fraction of the set of resources that can be physically tagged.

Comment: Yes and no. This link is specific to Tag Editor.
If you take AWS::EC2::TransitGateway for example, it's marked as NO but you can tag this ressource in the console :/